# Android 9patch software help needed

Tags: android, nine-patch

I am trying to create a nine patch `drawable`. I created an image with a white border and then opened it in `Draw9patch` software as explained here:

- http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html
- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch

I don't understand what I am supposed to do. I drew some kind of black border around it, and it gives me errors when I try to us it in my app. I have tried to draw a red border around it and it also gives the same errors that the nine patch is not valid.

Sometimes the area of the nine patch shows in pink and sometimes in green. I don't understand what it means and nothing is explained anywhere.

1. If the nine patch is not valid how can I know (before compiling the 
   app of course!)?
2. Do you know of any good tutorial for nine patch, explaining more then only how to open nine patch software?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing complicated in 9Patch image let me explain you via example(image)
[image]

`Top` and `Left` parts are stretchable area, this part will increase when your screen size increase

You can see pink dotted box in the 1st part of image that show `this` part will resize.

`Bottom` and `Right` parts are for content padding, your content will reside in this part only(reserve your content area).

You can see pink dotted box in the 2st part of image that show `this` part is for your content(string or etc).

General standard to be follow given in below image.

[image]

*Note: make 9patch of those image which having uniform color and shape(not complex curve).*

Comment: Thanks hotveryspicy, I have 2 questions: *when you say it is possible to use uniform drawable only

Comment: ... but my pic has only a small white border with rounded corners and the rest are empty pixels is it possible to use it? 2. I padd my strechable areas and when I click on the button "show bad patches" and it shows all my stretchable area in red, is it normal? and oups I have a question 3: do I have to erase pixels first? (the area around the "actual image" is empty (transparency)?

Answer (score 1):

A 9 patch image is an image that has stretchable areas defined.

These areas are defined in a special 1 pixel wide border around the area. Add black pixels to the top and left of this border to describe where the image can be stretched horizontally and vertically.

[Look Here for create nine patch image](http://www.androiddom.com/2011/05/android-9-patch-image-tutorial.html) .